# How to get commandline arguments for Java program bundled in Mac OSx App

Tags: java, macos, swing

I hope this is a dumb question, but I'm trying to take a java Swing application that I've developed and convert it to a Mac OS/X app file.  My program takes command line arguments.  I've been able to do the packaging using the appbundler-1.0.jar.  Problem is that when I launch from terminal using "open test.app --args zzz", the "zzz" is never passed into the main() method of the app.  I've see in another post, [How to ensure that open command invokes main function in the Java application on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658255/how-to-ensure-that-open-command-invokes-main-function-in-the-java-application-on), where it talks about registering an OpenFilesHandler, but it looks like that has gone away in Java 7.  Plus I want to reuse this code on multiple platforms, not just mac.  Any help or suggestions?

Comment: Are you launching the application for the first time, or is it already running and you are trying to run it again? (That is, is the application already in your dock with a dot under it?)

Comment: launching from the command line